# JSTL split Radio button into two lists

Tags: jstl

I am trying to split my Radio Button list into  "n" number of columns based on number of Rows. This is what I was trying, here programs is my list which currently has 17 Radio Buttons. I am trying to divide (17/2) rows and 2 columns currently.

```
 <c:set var="numRows" value="${fn:length(programs)/2-0.5}" />
    <c:set var="totalRows" value="${fn:length(programs)}" />
      <c:forEach begin="0" end="${numRows }" varStatus="i">
      <c:out  value="i=${i.index} " /> 
      <c:set var="rowStart" value="${i.index * numColumns}" />
      <fmt:formatNumber var="numColumns" value="${fn:length(programs) / numRows}"
         maxFractionDigits="0" />
      <c:forEach begin="0" end="${numColumns - 1}" varStatus="j" >
         <c:set var="index" value="${rowStart + j.index}"/>
         <c:out  value="j=${j.index} " /> 
              <c:choose>
                 <c:when test="${index lt fn:length(programs)}">
                      <c:forEach var="prgip" items="${programs}"> 
              <c:forEach begin="0" end="${totalRows }" varStatus="k"  var="prgip"             items="${programs}">
                      <input type="radio" value="${prgip.program_id}" name="program">  ${prgip.program_name} 
                       <c:out  value="k=${k.count} " /> 
                  </c:forEach>
               </c:forEach> 
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise>&nbsp;</c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
          </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Thanks in Advance
-Mim Jones.

Comment: I would think `numRows` ought to be an Integer value.  Why are you subtracting `0.5` from it?